# Contador de objetos por um sensor infra vermelho no Raspberry com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop, raspberry-pi

Olá amigos fiz um contador de objetos utilizando um sensor infravermelho e Python, porém gostaria de ajuda para refinar o código.

Pois este meu contador tem um problema, se o objeto parar em frente ao sensor o contador fica contando infinitamente, o meu objetivo é que este meu contador só fizesse a contagem quando o sensor mandasse o sinal de que ele foi ativado e desativado, fazendo com que ele realmente só fizesse a contagem quando um novo objeto passa-se em frente ao sensor.

Fiz essa programação em C++ no Arduino e é bem simples, porém em Python estou tendo dificuldades.

Agradeço a atenção.

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio

gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)

gpio.setup(36, gpio.IN)


Objetos=0

while True:

    sensor = gpio.input(36)
    if sensor ==  0:      
        Objetos+=1
        print("Objetos Detectados", Objetos)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando que `sensor` fique como 1 quando não há um objeto em frente ao sensor, você pode fazer um laço que espera o objeto passar; algo como:

```
from functools import partial

sensor_ir = partial(gpio.input, 36)

while True:
    if sensor_ir() == 0:
        objetos += 1
        # Enquanto o objeto não sair da frente...
        while sensor_ir() != 1:
            pass
```

Assim entra no `if` quando detecta um objeto e só sai do segundo `while` quando o objeto passar por completo. Também utilizei a função `functools.partial` para deixar o código mais legível, fazendo com que `sensor_ir()` seja equivalente a `gpio.input(36)`.

Mas preciso alertar que essa solução não prevê *bouncing* no sigal. Isto é, se o seu sensor variar entre 0 e 1 por intervalos curtos (ruídos) devido às características internas dele o sistema poderá ainda contabilizar errado.

Se você não quiser prender sua aplicação em um laço infinito, você pode criar uma *flag* que indica que o objeto atual foi ou não contabilizado.

```
contabilizado = False

while True:
    if sensor_ir() == 0 and not contabilizado:
        objetos += 1
        contabilizado = True
    elif sensor_ir() == 1:
        contabilizado = False
```

Assim, só será somado quando o sensor for 0 e `contabilizado` for falso; imediatamente `contabilizado` passa a ser verdadeiro, então nas próximas iterações em que sensor ainda for 0 o objeto não será contabilizado novamente. Somente a partir do momento que sensor passa a ser 1, que é quando o objeto deixa o sensor, `contabilizado` retorna a falso permitindo contar o próximo objeto.

---

Acerca do *bouncing*, é natural que um sensor possua ruídos entre as transições. Por exemplo, o gráfico abaixo representa o comportamento do sinal ao pressionar um botão. Deveria ficar em 0 quando o botão estiver livre e 1 quando for pressionado; porém, ao ser pressionado, haverá um ruído de transição em que o sinal variará entre 0 e 1 de forma "descontrolada". Para uma aquisição fiel do sinal é preciso tratar esse comportamento de forma a garantir que a leitura não seja feita neste período.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Anderson muito obrigado pela aula dada neste seu post, fiz aqui como o senhor me ensinou e está funcionando perfeitamente. Agradeço demais. Parabéns!!!!